# YUI 2.9 TreeView

Tags: treeview, yui

I am able to render a tree using YAHOO.widget.TreeView yui 2.9.
Using pre made

- 

tags

```
<ul> <li> Products </li> </ul>
```

I am able to get the label i.e Products using node.label

```
YAHOO.util.Event.on('allProductSaveButton','click',function() { 

    var hiLit = rightProductTree.getNodesByProperty('highlightState',1);

    if (YAHOO.lang.isNull(hiLit)) {  

        YAHOO.log("None selected"); 

    } else { 
        var labels = []; 



        for (var i = 0; i < hiLit.length; i++) {

               var node = hiLit[i];

               if(node.children.length<=0) {

            labels.push(hiLit[i].label); }
        } 
        alert("Highlighted nodes:\n" + labels.join("\n"), "info", "example"); 
    } 
});
```

I want to insert id of the Products in the html and get the id of label as well. so where should I place id attribute inside

or where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution. I inserted the label element inside the span element that was inside the li element i.e

```
 <ul>
    <li> <span> <label id="444" > Product </label> </span>
      </li>
     </ul>
```

then using YAHOO.util.Dom I traversed and got the id attribute of label element.

```
YAHOO.util.Event.on('GroupsProductSaveButton', 'click', function() {
            var hiLit = rightProductTree2.getNodesByProperty('highlightState', 1);
            if (YAHOO.lang.isNull(hiLit)) {
                alert("None selected");
            } else {
                var labels = [];

       for (var i = 0; i < hiLit.length; i++) {

               var node = hiLit[i];

               if(node.children.length<=0) {                
                       labels.push(YAHOO.util.Dom.get(hiLit[i].contentElId).getElementsByTagName('label')[0].getAttribute("value")); }
        }  
                alert("Highlighted nodes:\n" + labels.join("\n"), "info", "example");

                ProductGroupDWR.displaySelectedNodes(labels, function(data) {

                });
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can set your own `id` on the markup. TreeView is one of the oldest widgets in YUI 2 and it uses a particularly funny markup because the supported CSS styles in those days were quite pathetic, thus, what part of that funny markup are you going to apply that `id` to?

If what you want is to give a tree-node an identifier that you can later use to retrieve it, then use [custom properties](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/treeview/#customproperties).  Then, calling [getNodesByProperty](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.widget.TreeView.html#method_getNodesByProperty)  will allow you to retrieve the node by the value of that extra property.